# Pause CSS-animation of the circular menu to open and close

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a circular menu and I added `animation: pulse infinite`. My menu opens and is draggable.

I need to add pause-animated that it stops for a time when the menu is opened and closed.

I add "animation-play-state", "paused", it works, but after closing the menu the animation does not resume.

How to make the animation resume?

My code:

```css
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import "compass/css3";
body {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

.circular-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.circle a {
  z-index: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0081ee;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9ce;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/1.3 sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #0081ee;
}

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0081ee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, .5);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
}

.pulsing {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  perspective: 1000;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="circular-menu" id="draggable">
    <div class="circle">
      <!-- save the script -->
      <a href="" class="fa fa-check fa-2x" data-tooltip="сохранить текущий сценарий"></a>
      <!-- delete a step -->
      <a href="" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" data-tooltip="удалить шаг"></a>
      <!-- add a step -->
      <a href="" class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" data-tooltip="добавить шаг"></a>
      <!-- cancel the creation of script -->
      <a href="" class="fa fa-window-close fa-2x" data-tooltip="отменить создание сценария"></a>
      <!-- переход на другой сайт, не знаю, подходит ли иконка -->
      <a href="" class="fa fa-internet-explorer fa-2x" data-tooltip="перейти на другую страницу или сайт"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="pulsing" onclick="myFunction()">
      <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="pulsing"></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Or [here](https://codepen.io/tatyanavanina/pen/wvzMYYP).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of always adding style for pause animation, try to toggle it. Just as you do for the open and close menu.

In the snippet, all that I've changed is move `animation-state: paused` to a CSS `.paused` class, and toggle this class on click.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".circle a");

for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
items[i].style.left = (50 - 35 * Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

items[i].style.top = (50 + 35 * Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

let onClickHandler = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
document.querySelector(".circle").classList.toggle("open");
  document.querySelector(".menu-button").classList.toggle("paused");
    };

document.querySelector(".menu-button").onclick = onClickHandler;

let tooltipElem;
document.onmouseover = function (event) {
let target = event.target;
let tooltipHtml = target.dataset.tooltip;
if (!tooltipHtml) return;
tooltipElem = document.createElement("div");
tooltipElem.className = "tooltip";
tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltipHtml;
document.body.append(tooltipElem);
let coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();
let left = coords.left + (target.offsetWidth - tooltipElem.offsetWidth) / 2;
if (left < 0) left = 0;
let top = coords.top - tooltipElem.offsetHeight - 5;
if (top < 0) {
top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight + 5;
}
tooltipElem.style.left = left + "px";
tooltipElem.style.top = top + "px";
};

document.onmouseout = function (e) {
if (tooltipElem) {
tooltipElem.remove();
tooltipElem = null;
}
};

function setOnClickHandler() {
document.querySelector(".menu-button").onclick = onClickHandler;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#draggable").draggable({
start: function( event, ui ) {
document.querySelector(".menu-button").onclick = null;
},
stop: function( event, ui ) {
document.querySelector(".menu-button").onclick =
setTimeout(setOnClickHandler, 0);
}
});
});
```

```css
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import "compass/css3";

body {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

.circular-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1); 
}

.circle a {
  z-index: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0081ee;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9ce;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/1.3 sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #0081ee;
}

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0081ee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, .5);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.menu-button:hover, .menu-button.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(#0081ee, 0);
    
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
}

.pulsing
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  perspective: 1000;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
<nav class="circular-menu" id="draggable">
  <div class="circle">
    <!-- save the script -->
    <a href="" class="fa fa-check fa-2x" data-tooltip="сохранить текущий сценарий"></a>
    <!-- delete a step -->
    <a href="" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" data-tooltip="удалить шаг"></a>
    <!-- add a step -->
    <a href="" class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" data-tooltip="добавить шаг"></a>
    <!-- cancel the creation of script -->
    <a href="" class="fa fa-window-close fa-2x" data-tooltip="отменить создание сценария"></a>
    <!-- переход на другой сайт, не знаю, подходит ли иконка -->
    <a href="" class="fa fa-internet-explorer fa-2x" data-tooltip="перейти на другую страницу или сайт"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="pulsing">
  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x" id = "pulsing"></a>
    </div>
</nav>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

since JavaScript(JQuery) overrides CSS properties, if you want to change whatever back to normal, you need to do it with JavaScript.

change your function to this:

```
let onClickHandler = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = document.querySelector(".circle");
  document.querySelector(".circle").classList.toggle("open");
  if(a.className == "circle open")
    $(".menu-button").css("animation-play-state", "paused");
  else
    $(".menu-button").css("animation-play-state", "running");
};
```

I have no idea about JQuery so I do the stuff with JavaScript.

Comment: Don't work. why a.className == "circle open"?

Comment: since the function you have defined, adds and removes "open" class of "document.querySelector("circle")" object every time you click the button, so if the menu is open(class names are 'circle' and 'open'), animation needed to be paused , and if the menu is close(class name is circle), animation should be continued. @ТатьянаВанина

Comment: which part is not working???? check this out https://codepen.io/s-sohi/pen/NWRXKOd @ТатьянаВанина